# Find a string inside a string and update in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, substring

I have a table like this :

```
create table Fbank (id int, COCODE nvarchar(max))

insert into Fbank 
values (1, '<row xml:space="preserve" id="174580000041250.040002">
  <c1>HTG115960001</c1>
  <c2>14013514,48</c2>
  <c3>222</c3>
  <c4>BAL MIGRATED</c4>
  <c5>NULL</c5>
  <c6>NULL</c6>
  <c7>NULL</c7>
  <c8>9900</c8>
  <c9>11596</c9>
  <c10>20151017</c10>
  <c11>HTG</c11>
  <c12>NULL</c12>
  <c13>NULL</c13>
  <c14>FT1529010083</c14>
  <c15>1</c15>
  <c16>FT1529010083</c16>
  <c17>FT</c17>
  <c18>20151017</c18>
  <c19>NULL</c19>
  <c20>0</c20>
  <c21>5033_INPUTTER__OFS_AUTO.FT</c21>
  <c22>5033_INPUTTER_OFS_AUTO.FT</c22>
  <c23>1510181127</c23>
  <c24>HG0010001</c24>
</row>')
```

I need to replace the string inside the tag c24 tag..

Excepted output: I need to replace the letter 'G' to be replaced with 'T' like this inside c24 tag - HT0010001 and all the rest should be same unchanged...

What I tired:

```
declare @searchText varchar(20) = (
select SUBSTRING(COCODE,CHARINDEX('<c24>', COCODE),  7)
from FBNK_EB_SFF_ACCT_HI000)

update Fbank 
set cocode = STUFF(@searchText, CHARINDEX('<c24>', COCODE), 1, 'T')
```

Comment: If you stored your XML in the `xml` datatype, this would be such easier.

Comment: yes it is XML type.

Comment: Your question clearly shows it is not, @Mar1009 : `COCODE nvarchar(max)`. The `xml` and `nvarchar` data types are not the same.

Comment: @Mar1009 Is the datatype in your real table XML, or is it NVARCHAR(MAX) like your example shows?  There's a big difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code always begins with 'H', then I imagine it's easier to just have '<c24>H' be part of the string to replace, but then add it back again:

```
update Fbank 
set    COCODE = replace(cocode, '<c24>HG', '<c24>HT');
```

If it doesn't, then I'd say you're on the right track with `charindex` and `substring`.  But use `patindex` instead, and update `fbank` directly, don't put the search term into any variable.  If you're trying to split up your logic into parts, consider `cross apply`:

```
update      fb 
set         cocode = stuff(cocode, ix, 1, 'T')
from        Fbank fb
cross apply (select ix = patindex('%<c24>%', cocode) + 6) ap
where       substring(cocode, ix, 1) = 'G'
```